# datatable file export all data instead of 10 data

Tags: javascript, dom, datatable, datatables, export-to-csv

- [(video 1)](https://watch.screencastify.com/v/4r0zEjRullskzw0075zs) original/template can file export all data    from [datatable website](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export)
- [(video 2)](https://watch.screencastify.com/v/RjcDsVNj7LiF2ZYKyHCg) mine can only export 10 data

I apply the datatable file export template to mine website, but mine file export amount can only be 10 data in a time, how to handle this

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");
    const API_URL = newValue + '/api/event/list';
    var rowData;

    console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken);

    var accountType = localStorage.getItem("acc_type");
    var buttons = [
        {
            extend: "csv",
            text: "CSV",
            className: "btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg",
        },
        {
            extend: "excel",
            text: "Excel",
            className: "btn btn-outline-success btn-lg",
        },

    ];

    
    // Add a <div> to wrap the button, set it as row class
    var buttonRow = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    
    // Wrap each button in a <div> of col class, using the average width of the col class
    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
        var buttonCol = $('<div class="col"></div>').append(button);
        buttonRow.append(buttonCol);
    });
    
    
    if (accountType === "OP") {
        buttons = buttons.slice(2); // Keep only custom buttons, remove other buttons
    }

 
    $("#example tbody").on("click", "button", function (event) {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        rowData = data;
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data);
    });

    $("#exampleModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data("whatever");
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        modal.find(".modal-title").text("Update data " + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find(".modal-body input");

        if (button.attr("id") == "AddedNew_Data") {
            inputFields.val("");
        } else {
            var keys = Object.keys(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
                $(inputFields[i]).val(rowData[keys[i]]);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#exampleModal").on("show.bs.modal", (e) => {
        $(".modalTextInput").val("");
        let btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
        let id = btn.data("id");
        $(".saveEdit").data("id", id);
    });

    $(".saveEdit").on("click", function () {
        let id = $(this).data("id");
        saveNote(id);
        $("#exampleModal").modal("toggle");
    });
});
```

Is that I accidently overwrite built-in funtion of datatble? I'm not sure where I get wrong